# Multiple google maps on different sites in one js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps

I'm trying to display multiple Google Maps on different pages with one js file. This is my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log('itt vagyok')
function initMap() {

    var planjka = new google.maps.LatLng(44.571137, 14.888191);
    var zrce = new google.maps.LatLng(44.540586, 14.914177);

    var mapCanvasPlanjka = document.getElementById('mapPlanjka');
    var mapCanvasZrce = document.getElementById('mapZrce');


    var mapOptionsPlanjka = {
        center: planjka,
        zoom: 16,
        panControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var mapOptionsZrce = {
        center: zrce,
        zoom: 16,
        panControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }  

    var mapPlanjka = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvasPlanjka, mapOptionsPlanjka);
    var mapZrce = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvasZrce, mapOptionsZrce);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

});

On the first site (planjka) I can see the map, but on the second site (zrce) nothing shows but on both sites I get an error message:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
    at Object._.pg (js:85)
    at new ug (js:87)
    at initMap (mapsnew.js:27)

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: It seems like the page does not contain HTML element with id `mapZrce`

Comment: First of all try to remove your document.ready, initMap will be called while page is finished loading anyway with your listener. It's just a declaration of function, nothing is trigggered until the map listener call the function

Comment: MysterX! i have mapZrce id. thanks for your respons

Comment: Pierre Granger! i remove "document.ready" but still the same problem! thanks

Comment: Saddly i can not find a solution to this problem, so i seperate the files, each google map has his each js file, so works grate